# Typescript : Filter on keyof type parameter

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript 3.8.3 and try to dynamically find the keys of a certain type and use them to produce an other object.

I have a `Detail` object and want to use it to dynamically generate a `Column` object only based on the properties of type `Desc`.
Here is a simplified code of what i want to do :

```
// Model
interface Desc {
    creationDate: Date;
}

interface Address extends Desc {
    zipCode: number;
    adressName: string;
}

interface Order extends Desc {
    id: number;
    orderName: string;
}

interface Detail {
    name: string;
    address: Address[];
    orders: Order[];
}
// Table column configuration
interface Column<T> {
    field: keyof T;
    active: boolean;
}

type ColumnConfig<T> = { [P in keyof T]: Column<T[P] extends Desc ? P : never>[] };

const config: ColumnConfig<Detail> = {
    address: [
        {
            field: "zipCode",
            active: true 
        }, 
        {
            field: "addressName",
            active: true
        }
    ],
    order: [
        {
            field: "id",
            active:false
        },
        {
            field: "orderName",
            active: false
        }
    ],
    // Detail.name should not be available but it is

}
```

How can i benefit from the help of the compiler to construct my `config` object and thus be able to detect any errors if my `Detail` object changes ?

Thanks !

Comment: Hi Nainpo, I'm seeing that you are declaring `address` as an Array. So do you need something like `Column<Address>[]`? Could you add an example of the type you *desire* as the output?

Comment: In fact it was a typo, until now i always want an array of objects, but the UnboxArray could be useful one day ! :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In order to exclude some columns for a mapped type, we need to use an intermediate helper type, allowing us to select only the **keys** respecting our condition, `T[K] extends Desc`:

```
type ConfigurableColumnsKeys<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Desc ? K : never
}[keyof T];
```

Given this, `ColumnConfig` just need to map over this generic type instead of the original `keyof T`:

```
type ColumnConfig<T extends object> = {
  [P in ConfigurableColumnsKeys<T>]: Column<P>[] 
};
```

Then your config object will be correctly validated:

```
  // Error
  name: [
    { field: 'abc', active: true }
  ]
```

If you need to allows *arrays* too (i.e. `Address[]` instead of `Address`), you can change the helper type, checking for `T extends Desc[]`. Furthermore, you will need an `UnboxArray` helper too, to extract item value `Order[]` -> `Order` for your column config:

```
type ConfigurableColumnsKeys<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Desc ? K : T[K] extends Desc[] ? K : never
}[keyof T];

type UnboxArray<T> = T extends Array<infer V> ? V : T;

type ColumnConfig<T extends object> = {
  [P in ConfigurableColumnsKeys<T>]: Column<UnboxArray<T[P]>>[]
};
```

You can see it at work in the following playground: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=35&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=1#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-tblXDSha1gYQyUhAjhEIj2eDAARKpNNoIMuADQz+f-YBAhjOfQQXesHfz+6XxcvZcTtoZTdb5BTZAASSgVGACDgFQqH2fMAAAtgDEVw4CBZp1mgT8oGfDBQD8YDoBQAB3OAxDgZB1QoWNsKAlBCh4PwdAQCo4D2cgqAAQl3CxSQPXRj1PS92EIEYL3xQZ+mnS853nG8Vzibc6OaBjDweX8MBY+dz13fiF2AJ5b16dI6hEy96MBXR4AqaSzyUDilFfABRA1UiUWpMkjeSHiUpdkAAcnmBBHOffcJOY5A2OQEYOFYIA)

Comment: Thank you it was the trick i was searching for ! I still have one question, is it possible to have a compiler error if i forget one of the required field ? i.e `orders` or `address` ?

Comment: In fact it worked already, thank you for your help @leonardfactory !

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is an answer to the original question but...

A Typescript 4.1 feature may help others finding this question needing to filter out properties based on the **key** and not the **value** of the property. It's called 'key remapping'.

For instance you could remove properties with a certain name or prefix.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as

Comment: Nice add to the original question ! Delightful