# Filtering keyof in typescript mapped types works unexpectedly

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to extract the keys of an interface (using `keyof`) that match an event handler pattern - that is `(CustomEvent) => void`.

I have a method that seems to work and does extract only keys that match `(CustomEvent) => void`, however, it also extracts keys who's type is `() => void`.

Is there a way to extract only keys of types that conform to `(CustomEvent) => void`?

The method is based on the questions
[Filter interface keys for a sub-list of keys based on value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63553724/filter-interface-keys-for-a-sub-list-of-keys-based-on-value-type)
and
[Typescript : Filter on keyof type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61506794/typescript-filter-on-keyof-type-parameter)

In the example below

```
export interface JayCustomEvent {}

type EventHandler = (e: JayCustomEvent) => void;

type FilteredKeys<T, U> = { [P in keyof T]: P extends string ? (T[P] extends U ? P : never) : never}[keyof T];

interface AComponentEvent extends JayCustomEvent {}
interface AComponent {
    anEvent(e: AComponentEvent): void,
    noParamFunction(): void,
    someOtherFunction(a: number): void
    someProp: string
}

let a: FilteredKeys<AComponent, EventHandler> = 'anEvent'
let b: FilteredKeys<AComponent, EventHandler> = 'noParamFunction'
let c: FilteredKeys<AComponent, EventHandler> = 'someOtherFunction'
let d: FilteredKeys<AComponent, EventHandler> = 'someProp'
```

I expect assignment `a` to be working, while `b`, `c` and `d` should not.
However, assignments `a` and `b` are valid, while only `c` and `d` are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved exactly what I need, so posting here to help others.

Given the definitions

```js
type Func0 = () => void
type Func1 = (x: any) => void
type DOMeventHandler<E> = (((this: GlobalEventHandlers, ev: E) => any) | null)
```

As @jsejcksn noted in his answer (which is correct), `Func0` does extend `Func1`. However, we can use this to construct a type that matches exactly the keys of an object who are one parameter functions.

The answer is here, following explanation

```js
type EventHandlerKeys<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]:
    P extends string ?
        (T[P] extends Func1 ?
            (T[P] extends Func0 ? never : P) :
            T[P] extends DOMeventHandler<any> ? P : never) :
        never
}[keyof T];
```

The trick is to match on `Func1`, which selects both functions of zero or one parameter. Then we match again on `Func0` and return `never` for zero parameter functions, and the actual property type for one parameter functions.

Here we also match on `DOMEventHandler` as an additional bonus with another conditional branch.

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping utility seems fine.

I think you might be surprised to learn that [functions with lower arity are subtypes of compatible higher-arity ones](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/338471/31737). Consider the following example:

```ts
type AssignableTo<T, U> = T extends U ? true : false;

type Fn0Params = () => void;
type Fn1Param = (p: unknown) => void;

declare const ex1: AssignableTo<Fn0Params, Fn1Param>;
ex1 // true

type Fn0ParamsNever = (...args: never) => void;

declare const ex2: AssignableTo<Fn0ParamsNever, Fn1Param>;
ex2 // false
```

So, by typing your `noParamFunction` as having parameters of type `never`, you can prevent it from being assignable to `EventHandler`:

```ts
noParamFunction(...args: never): void
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=12&ssc=13&pln=1&pc=1#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-PFgIg0uNJoJph6FvXok3i1A4FiIAB5YAAC2G7dQne7qFM6FmwkMmCHPOizaLE8MEB0ggIvnHQnNihJilwmXXGiFIvFkuloarkeA5GjNLpwxo9AAOSlimgG3hAmSYBIgrCsMooSlKRDvrm1Ywt+Ka-hw9IAVAgGtg8i7LmkYF3ps0FPnBL6IcheZoVAP60lh-5eIBh7TnOC4dl2xHgZkHDkbBgjwa+SE5rRX70RhjHYSxbEnmegFAA)

> Perpendicular to your question: If you're actually working with [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent)s, then you might want to use `(event: CustomEvent<JayCustomEvent>) => void`